# How can i add Navigation menu items with icon title and subtitle in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]How can i add Navigation menu items with icon title and subtitle in Kotlin as shown in the image? And how to handle the selection of each item and selected item should have background with some color in Navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!-- custom_nav_menu_item.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**In your nav_menu.xml, specify the custom layout for each menu item:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:title=""
            android:actionLayout="@layout/custom_nav_menu_item"
            android:checked="false"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:title=""
            android:actionLayout="@layout/custom_nav_menu_item"
            android:checked="false"/>
        <!-- Add more items as needed -->
    </group>
</menu>
```

**In your activity or fragment**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    // Inflate the custom layout for each menu item
    val menu = navView.menu
    for (i in 0 until menu.size()) {
        val menuItem = menu.getItem(i)
        val actionView = menuItem.actionView as LinearLayout

        val iconImageView = actionView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.nav_icon)
        val titleTextView = actionView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nav_title)
        val subtitleTextView = actionView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nav_subtitle)

        // Set icon, title, and subtitle for each menu item
        iconImageView.setImageResource(iconResId) // Set your icon resource
        titleTextView.text = "Title" // Set your title
        subtitleTextView.text = "Subtitle" // Set your subtitle
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            // Handle Home
        }
        R.id.nav_profile -> {
            // Handle Profile
        }
        // Handle other items
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: Here at getting null val actionView = menuItem.actionView as LinearLayout

please help